# complex entityframework query

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have two tables:
NewsRooms ( NrID[int] , NrName [string]);
RawNews( RnID [int], NrID[string]);

realtion is RawNews 1 * NewsRooms

so i use checkboxes for NewsRooms and save the ids as a string in RawNews like this ';1;2;'

now for example i have a list which contains some NrIDs . i want to select every RawNew which it's NrID contains any of the ids inside that list.

here is my code:

```
var temp = Util.GetAvailibleNewsRooms("ViewRawNews");
            List<string> ids = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in temp)
                ids.Add(";" + item.NrID.ToString() + ";");

            model = db.RawNews.Where(r => r.NrID.Any(ids));
```

the line model = db.RawNews.Where(r => r.NrID.Any(ids)); is wrong and i don't know how to write this code. please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, i found the solution myself so i post it here maybe some other guy need it some day!!

```
model = model.Where(r => ids.Any(i => r.NrID.Contains(i)));
```